# sys.dm_os_volume_stats problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Today I have been having quite an interesting issue, which I can't seem to fix. I am getting drive information for a Failover Cluster Instance SQL Server 2012. These drives are Volume Mount Points. For about 40 instances this runs perfectly except for one FCL this does not retrieve the right drive.

The query I use is

```
select 
 case when type_desc = 'ROWS' then 'DATA' when type_desc = 'LOG' then 'LOG' else 'Unknown' end as DataOrLog,
    mf.database_id,
    mf.name,
    mf.physical_name,
    Drive.volume_mount_point,
    Drive.logical_volume_name 
    from sys.master_files mf
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(mf.database_id, mf.FILE_ID) Drive
    where mf.database_id not in (1,2,3,4)
```

The normal result I get for this query is.

[image: NormalSituation]

This is the result I get with the problem case.

[image: WrongSituation]

What can be the reason that *sys.dm_os_volume_stats* can't find the right volume?

Is it some wrong configuration at FCL level?

Why does my sys.master_files show the right drive but the cross applied fileID to *sys.dm_os_volume_stats* not ? How does this connection work with this DM?

I also checked the drive itself and the file is definitely in the right drive.

Comment: What do you get when you just do it for one file: `select volume_mount_point, logical_volume_name from sys.dm_os_volume_stats(5,1)`?  Also, what version of windows?

Comment: then he resolves, Windows server 2012 R2

Comment: I meant to select the log file: `select volume_mount_point, logical_volume_name from sys.dm_os_volume_stats(5,2)`

Comment: I know ;) yes that  resolves